# Google Spreadsheet search /w multiple variables, bitwise 1 or 0 when found

Tags: google-sheets

Hi I would like to lookup three variables and return YES if they are all three found in the columns above us. My sample function is provided below.

```
=ArrayFormula( SUM( (T$2:T18=T19) * (C$2:C18=C19) * (K$2:K18="✓")) )
```

The problem is that I would like for it to work as incremental check. So if check 1 is correct it returns 1, if both 1 and 2 are found it returns 1+2, if both 1,2 and 3 are found it returns 1+2+4. (I think bitwise is the only solution)

In short, instead of this resulting in 2

```
111 = 1
001 = 0
101 = 0
111 = 1
```

It should check column 1 first. If found return 1 (for found in the column) then if the first was found check 2nd column, if found return 2 (for found in second column also)

[Link to sample data attached](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TPG13_iVhVaXlP8cpvHvELzmThk7hcRBSAe0whlOAm4/edit?usp=sharing)

Can this be done?

(ps. based on 1, 2 or 3 we set status new, in progress or complete)

Comment: Maybe a example linked sheet will help.

Comment: I don't think **ArrayFormula()** is the correct way to go. You should probably use **IF()** instead

Comment: @Vasim Added sample data

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=(T$2:T18=T19)+((T$2:T18=T19)*(C$2:C18=C19))+((T$2:T18=T19)*(C$2:C18=C19)*(K$2:K19=K19)*2)
```

Comment: thanks, understand what you are trying to do. Good one. #/VALUE error though. Stttrange one. "An Array Value could not be found"